# Play store uninstalled, Reinstalled not working

Tags: google-play-store

I rooted my phone I accidentally deleted something that made my playstore shut down immediately. I tried everything I have found on the internet. Clear data / clear cache. Factory reset. Uninstalled and reinstalled. Im still getting unfortunately google has stopped. Looking for help. I did several back up nandriod titanium but I dont know how to install back ups. Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your device and ROM you can either reinstall your operating system (ROM) or you can reinstall the gApps (Google apps).

Normally the apps come in a flashable zip file that you can install (flash) via recovery (a secondary minimal operating system).

Depending on your device the ROM can come in a flashable zip file or a variety of other files (tar.gz, md5, etc...) so you will have to figure that one out.

You can download gapps for Android 4.4.4 here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942

When downloading gApps you will want to match the version up with your device so that they are compatible with it. E.G. You are running 4.1.2 so you will download the 4.1.x compatible gApps.

Hope this helps!